# Store data from 10.5.4 os x on external hard drive

Tags: macos, backup, osx-yosemite

I would like to make a backup of my data from old MacBook. The version of OS is: 10.5.4 os x

I would like to copy the data to the external harddrive and encrypt it. Then I would like to be able to mount this drive to this old 10.5.4 os x as well as to my new machine which has installed 10.10.2 yosemite.

Is it possible? What would be the best way to do that? Is SAMSUNG STSHX-M101TCB a good choice?

Comment: Does Time Machine offer to create encrypted backups in 10.5.4? If so, that would be a viable option.

Comment: Are you trying to dual boot with both versions of OSX?